# Dynamically inject repository in generic services with nestjs

Tags: dependency-injection, authorization, nestjs

I am building an authorization service for my nestjs app.

For every protected resource on my app (`Media`, `Game`, ...), I have a `*RoleEntity` associated (`MediaRoleEntity`, `GameRoleEntity`, ...) that defines what a user can do with a specific resource. Each one of this `*RoleEntity` implements `RoleEntityInterface`:

```js
export interface RoleEntityInterface<T extends ResourceEntity> {
  resource: T;
  user: UserEntity;
  role: string;
}
```

Each protected entity (`MediaEntity`, `GameEntity`, ...) extends `ResourceEntity`.

Now I want to build a generic provider `RoleService`, responsible for database interaction:

```js
@Injectable()
export class RoleService<T extends ResourceEntity> {
  readonly roleRepository: Repository<RoleEntityInterface<T>>;

  async read(roleDto: Partial<RoleDto<T>>): Promise<RoleEntityInterface<T>> {
    return this.roleRepository.findOne({
      where: { ...roleDto },
    });
  }

  async create(roleDto: RoleDto<T> | RoleDto<T>[]): Promise<void> {
    await this.roleRepository.insert(roleDto);
  }
}
```

And I want inject this service in guards, interceptors...

Problem, I don't know how to do that, more precisely:

- How can I dynamically inject the roleRepository ? (I imagine some kind of factory has to be involved.)

**REAL USE CASE**

I want to be able to protect resources with a guard:

```js
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard<T extends ResourceEntity> implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private roleService: RoleService<T>,
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

Now in a controller, when I use

```js
@Role('Admin')
@UseGuards(RoleGuard<MediaEntity>)
Get()
...
```

It would be perfect if the whole thing magically works :), ie correct roleService with correct roleRepository are properly injected.

I am completely new to nestjs and typescript (and never played with angular neither) so maybe the whole approach is wrong..

Comment: Can u please modify your question and show, how is your module look like, to get the whole picture of the problem? Moreover, your approach is interesting, but you have to define your authorization by role in slightly different way.
Show your module file and i'll try my best to answer on it.